# Using a list element to retrieve a value from e result object

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to get a subset of whois info for a list of IP addresses.

These statements worked:

```
01  oWhois = IPWhois(sIP)
02  resWhoisInfo = oWhois.lookup_whois()
03  sWhois_CIDR = resWhoisInfo["nets"][0]['cidr']
04  sWhois_Name = resWhoisInfo["nets"][0]['name']
0N  ...
```

Until I got a result that was incomplete and I got an index error.

So rather than putting an if/else statement around lines 03, 04, 0N, I thought I'd be clever and define the following:

```
  nWhoisCIDR = 0
  nWhoisName = 1
  nWhoisCountry = 2
  nWhois... = N

  lWhoisItems=[[nWhoisCIDR, 'cidr'],[nWhoisName, 'name'],[nWhoisCountry, 'country'],[nWhois..., 'whatever']]
```

So that I could use a loop and reference items like this:

```
  for i in lWhoisItems:
    try:
      lWhoisResults = lWhoisResults + resWhoisInfo["nets"][0][(lWhoisItems[i][1])]
    except IndexError:
      lWhoisResults = lWhoisResults + "no value found"
```

But when I try to that I get an error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list" - even though (lWhoisItems[0][1]) == 'cidr'... (and so on).

So my question, how can I make this work? Or is this style of programming just not very Pythonish? If not could you please point me to (an example of) a solution that pretty much does the same?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you create a [mre] with some example input and expected output? Also, if your code gives an error, add the full stacktrace to the question, so we can see at which line the error occurred etc.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do? It seems like you could probably loop through each dictionary directly, if, say, you want to print or store some/all of the fields. Alternatively, you could call its `.get()` method for various keys.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost right you just missed this detail. If you print `i` in the for loop by adding this line here.

```py
  for i in lWhoisItems:
    print(i)
    try:
      lWhoisResults = lWhoisResults + resWhoisInfo["nets"][0][(lWhoisItems[i][1])]
    except IndexError:
      lWhoisResults = lWhoisResults + "no value found"
```

You will get the output something like this

```
[0, 'cidr']
[1, 'name']
[2, 'country']
...
```

So you can use unpacking to get the index you need.

```py
  for i, key in lWhoisItems:
    try:
      lWhoisResults = lWhoisResults + resWhoisInfo["nets"][0][lWhoisItems[i]]
    except IndexError:
      lWhoisResults = lWhoisResults + "no value found"
```

You can do even better by accessing the key itself.

```py
  for i, key in lWhoisItems:
    try:
      lWhoisResults = lWhoisResults + resWhoisInfo["nets"][0][key]
    except IndexError:
      lWhoisResults = lWhoisResults + "no value found"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, that looks very promising, try that out tomorrow. I'll post the results.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't wait so tried right away :) The "+" generates errors, so this is the way to go:

```
for i, key in lWhoisItems:
  try:
    lWhoisResults.append(quotestr(resWhoisInfo["nets"][0][key]))
  except IndexError:
    lWhoisResults.append("no value found")
```

Also, since I'm writing this to a csv file and lWhoisResults is obviously a list, one should do the following:

```
fOutput.write("\n" + sIP + "," + sHost + ","  + "," .join(lWhoisResults))
```

Don't know why the 2nd comma is needed, but that produces the correct results. Otherwise the first value in the list is concatenated to the value of "sHost".

Thanks again, this is getting me what I need.

Comment: Forgot to mention, quotestr is a function that adds quotes to whatever it's given ad retuns an empty quoted string in case there's no value.